# ActiveMQ consumer waiting for redelivered messages instead of processing other messages in the queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.15.6, and I would like to take 2 messages from a queue, process them, and commit the transactional session.

However, if an `Exception` is thrown messages are mark as redelivered and returned to queue, and the application waits until the redelivery delay expires and after that it try to process them again.

I need to process other messages in then queue until delayed messages are ready again to deliver.

Code is only proof of concept :)

```java
public class ActiveMqService {

    private final ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf;
    private final Connection connection;
    private final Session session;
    private final Queue queue;
    private final MessageConsumer consumer;

    public ActiveMqService() throws JMSException {
        cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = cf.getRedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(5000L);
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(5000L);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(100);
        ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy = cf.getPrefetchPolicy();
        prefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(2);
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
        connection = cf.createConnection(); //credentials
        session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        queue = session.createQueue("test");
        connection.start();
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void read() throws JMSException {

        while (true) {
            List messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                Message message = consumer.receive(1000L);
                if (message != null) {
                    messages.add(message);
                } else {
                    break; // no more messages available for this batch
                }
            }

            if (messages.size() > 0) {
                try {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    if (1 == random.nextInt(2)) {
                        for (Object message : messages) {
                            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                            log.info("Message {}", textMessage.getText());
                        }
                        session.commit();
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception("vyjimka");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    List mess = new ArrayList();
                    for (Object message : messages) {
                        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                        mess.add(textMessage.getText());
                    }
                    log.info("rollbackuju message {}", mess);
                    session.rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In log you can see, that after rollback application wait 5 seconds (set delay) to redelivred messages, but don't process another messages in queue.

```
2021-12-09 17:05:47.605  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 7
2021-12-09 17:05:47.606  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 3
2021-12-09 17:05:47.612  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : rollbackuju message [8, 5]
2021-12-09 17:05:52.623  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : rollbackuju message [8, 5]
2021-12-09 17:05:57.634  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 8
2021-12-09 17:05:57.635  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 5
2021-12-09 17:05:57.642  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 9
2021-12-09 17:05:57.642  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 2
2021-12-09 17:05:57.648  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : rollbackuju message [6, 4]
2021-12-09 17:06:02.655  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 6
2021-12-09 17:06:02.656  INFO 14500 --- [           main] c.example.testactivemq.ActiveMqService   : Message 4
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Active MQ 5.15.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `setNonBlockingRedelivery(true)` on your `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` in `ActiveMqService()`, e.g.:

```java
public ActiveMqService() throws JMSException {
    cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    cf.setNonBlockingRedelivery(true);
    ...
}
```

The comment for this method states:

> ```
>  /**
>   * When true a MessageConsumer will not stop Message delivery before re-delivering Messages
>   * from a rolled back transaction.  This implies that message order will not be preserved and
>   * also will result in the TransactedIndividualAck option to be enabled.
>   */
> ```

Additionally, you'll probably want to set your prefetch size higher than the current value of `2` since the 2 messages waiting to be redelivered will prevent additional messages from being fetched from the broker.

Comment: yes it works! Thank you very much

Comment: and for addition prefetch must be bigger then 2.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer.